# JS сгенерировать случайное имя из 2-х input

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Если у меня есть 2 input, и в каждом из них я напишу имя, как я могу сгенерировать случайное имя из 2-х input с кодом JavaScript, нажимая кнопку?

Comment: Внесите в свой вопрос больше ясности, желательно с примером. По какому принципу должно генерироваться имя? Что сделали вы?

Comment: `сгенерировать случайное имя`  это так чтоли – Вася, Петя = Песя?

Comment: да, используя только JS

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  var randName = $("#inp" + temp).val();
  alert(randName);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="inp0" />
  <input type="text" id="inp1" />
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me!!!" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: a как это будет без jquery?

Comment: `var btn = document.getelementbyid("btn");btn.onclick = function(){ var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);var inp = document.getelementbyid("inp"+temp);alert(inp.value);};` писал с телефона...могут быть помарки